# Как узнать ID только что созданной строки mysql?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Доброго дня!

Я разрабатываю свой проект на CI. Столкнулся с задачей создания тикета. Тикеты имеют две таблицы в БД: 
tickets - здесь хранится информация о создатели тикета, дата и заголовок
tickets_comment - здесь все сообщения из тикета.

Для корректной работы, я должен получить значение ID из таблицы tickets, чтобы прикрепить первое сообщение к этому тикету.

Как это сделать?

**controler**

```
function add_ticket()
    {

        $user = $this->input->post("user");
        $title = $this->input->post("title");
        $message = $this->input->post("message");

        $ticket = $this->tickets_model->add_ticket(array(
                  "date"   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                  "user"   => $user,
                  "title"  => $title,
                    "status" => $status,
                    "comment" => "0"
                )
            );

        $comments = $this->tickets_model->add_admin_comment(array(
                  "id_ticket"       => $tickets['id'],
                  "date"          => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                  "user"          => lang('admin disputes admin'),
                  "role"          => "2",
                    "comment"       => $comment,
                )
            );

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('admin trans add_success'));
        redirect(site_url("admin/users"));

    }
```

**model**

```
function add_ticket($data) 
    {
        $this->db->insert("tickets", $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    function add_admin_comment($data) 
    {
        $this->db->insert("tickets_comment", $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: а какая ошибка? судя по всему он возвращает id тикета

Comment: `"id_ticket"       => $ticket,`